# Can raw sensor data be stored on Google Fit store?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am using Google Fit with an Android device.  However, all the preset data items are exercise related data points and units.

I would like to store raw sensor data that is then processed by the device or a webapp.

Is this possible (good practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is provision for [custom data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types) so you could undoubtedly store the data.  If it's a good idea is a different issue.  You need to outline what your trying to achieve in a bit more detail.  What sensor data are you talking about and what processing do you want to do with it?  If you can do it on the device my gut feeling is store it some other way e.g. in a file then do the processing you want and possibly store the results in FIT.